# How to extend a class from Model.tt

Tags: c#, linq

I've used C# in VS2012 with LINQ to connect to a simple sql database mdf file.
I can see the tables from the database as classes in Solution Explorer, Model1.edmx, Model1.tt.

I want to extend the class and add extra features to it but it doesn't have a constructor I recognize, I cant pass variables to it to create objects.

Is it even possible to do what I'm trying?

Thanks all

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you or not, if not ask! :)

Comment: Extend in what way? This is very unclear. Maybe you can give an example. (By editing your question).

Answer (score 1):

Use partial classes. The T4 templates generate the classes as partial classes which you can easily extend using partial classes.

So leave the CS files generated by the T4 tool alone, and create CS files that are in the same namespace and assembly with classes like this:

```
public partial class NameOfClassInT4
{
    //your own custom stuff here.
}
```

Yes, you can have two partial classes with the same name, that's the whole idea: to define the class in more than one files. This is especially useful in your case where one definition is auto generated and your modifications might be overwritten, so create another separate file and customize the class in another file as if there where in the same file.